# Noob Question: How to import some imodule in Python?

Tags: python, linux

I am using Python 2.5 on CentOS 5.5

I have got a file called `MultipartPostHandler.py`, I am supposed to use it like this:

```
import MultipartPostHandler
```

But I dont know where should I put the file `MultipartPostHandler.py` so I can use it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got the file `MultipartPostHandler.py` from here `http://hoisie.com/post/python_sending_a_multipartformdata_request_with_urllib2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

> When a module named spam is imported,
> the interpreter searches for a file
> named spam.py in the current
> directory, and then in the list of
> directories specified by the
> environment variable PYTHONPATH. This
> has the same syntax as the shell
> variable PATH, that is, a list of
> directory names. When PYTHONPATH is
> not set, or when the file is not found
> there, the search continues in an
> installation-dependent default path;
> on Unix, this is usually
> .:/usr/local/lib/python.
>
> Actually, modules are searched in the
> list of directories given by the
> variable sys.path which is initialized
> from the directory containing the
> input script (or the current
> directory), PYTHONPATH and the
> installation- dependent default. This
> allows Python programs that know what
> they’re doing to modify or replace the
> module search path.

So, you have to put it into the **current directory** or use **sys.path** to show your program where the searched module is.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to put it in the same folder as the code you're writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you got it from somebody who provides an installer, then to be safe, just run the installer.

If it's just something you grabbed specifically for this project, put it in the same folder as the `.py` files that you're writing.

Otherwise (if you're planning to use it for a few projects and don't want to copy/paste the file), the safest place to put it is probably in the `/lib/site-packages` sub-directory of the directory where Python is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest - yes, is to put it in the same directory where you have the importer python code. Also, you can export `PYTHONPATH` environment variable which points to the directory (or directories separated by `:`) where you have `MultipartPostHandler.py`. Another option: make it distributable. This will be useful if you are going to publish your code.